# Rally custom data store will not update

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

My Rally custom data store will not update. Im having the problem described in [this][1] post.

My scenario is: I will be adding rows to a grid, which has a custom data store. then I sort a grid column, and all the new rows I added get deleted. There is nothing fancy about my custom store, and I've tried autoSync:true, but that does nothing.

Are custom stores Read-only, in the sense that any changes made to the original data are transient and will get deleted with a reload()?

This is my store that I add to the rallygrid

```
        me.customStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', { 
            data: customData,
            listeners:{
                load: function(customStore){
                    //do some stuff
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code for the memory proxy and it makes sense why nothing was getting added or removed or updating correctly with the `Rally.data.custom.Store` store. You have to override the create and destroy methods of the memory proxy.

**CURRENT MEMORY PROXY FUNCTIONS**

These are functions that are used to create and destroy records for the memory proxy. As you can see, they dont create or destroy any records...

```
updateOperation: function(operation, callback, scope) {
    var i = 0,
        recs = operation.getRecords(),
        len = recs.length;

    for (i; i < len; i++) {
        recs[i].commit();
    }
    operation.setCompleted();
    operation.setSuccessful();

    Ext.callback(callback, scope || this, [operation]);
},    

create: function() {
    this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
},

destroy: function() {
    this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

**CORRECT MEMORY PROXY SETUP**

Below is how to instantiate a custom store that will actually add and remove records in the custom store

```
    me.customStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
        data: //customData
        model: //modelType
        autoSync:true,
        proxy: {
            type:'memory',
            create: function(operation) {
                var me = this;
                operation.getRecords().forEach(function(record){
                    console.log('adding record', record);
                    me.data.push(record);
                });
                this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            destroy: function(operation) {
                var me = this;
                operation.getRecords().forEach(function(record){
                    console.log(record);
                    for(var i = 0;i<me.data.length;++i){
                        if(/*me.data[i] == record*/ ){
                            me.data.splice(i, 1);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
                this.updateOperation.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },
        listeners://listener stuff here
    });
```